# how to insert multiple item in php using an entilty class with set and get

Tags: php, oop

I'm having trouble inserting two phone numbers using set and get in php. My class works well if it is one phone number, as soon as I try to enter two numbers it enters null/empty. My idea is to enter more than one phone number from the html form. Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="form-field-1-1" placeholder="Text Field" name="telefone[]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" />

<input type="text" id="form-field-1-1" placeholder="Text Field" name="telefone[]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" />
```

--------------PHP CLASS----------

```
class Telefone {
    private $telefone = array();
    public function getTelefone() {
        return $this->telefone;
    }
    public function setTelefone($telefone) {
        $this->telefone[] = $telefone;
    }
}
```

-------CONTROLLER IMPLAMENTATION---------

```
$inserirDados = new AgendaEventoDAO();

$tlfn = new Telefone();

$tlfn->setTelefone($_POST['telefone'] ? trim($_POST['telefone']) : '');

if($inserirDados->inserirTelefone($tlfn,$usuario)){

    print "Telefone do Agendamento Inserido com sucesso!";

}
```

--------DAO-----------------------------

```
public function inserirTelefone(Telefone $tlfn, SiteUserInfo $usuario) {

    $connection = new cnx();
    $connection->connect();
    $telefon = $tlfn->getTelefone();
    $ce_usuario = $usuario->getUser_id();
    
     
    foreach ($telefon as $telefone) {
        $stmt = $connection->myconn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbltelefone_agenda (telefone_agenda,ce_agenda_evento) VALUES (?,?)");            
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $telefone,$ce_usuario);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $connection->close();
        echo("<script>console.log('PHP: Telefone inserido com sucesso!');</script>");
        return $stmt;
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You should make corrections by editing your question rather than adding code in the comments. Click the [edit] link under your question. Also, indent your code blocks four spaces and be sure there's a blank line before them to get them completely formatted as code.

Comment: It looks like you're referring to `$_POST['telefone']` as a string in your PHP code, but `name="telefone[]"` in the HTML form means its value in `$_POST` will be an array, not a string.

Comment: to add to @Don'tPanic's comment, eve_descri is in a textarea and you're trying to bind it as an integer in bind_param. You never actually showed us where the $usuario var came from.

Comment: am sorry but am having hard time posting the html tags <div>
<input type="text" id="form-field-1-1" placeholder="Text Field" name="telefone[]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" />
<input type="text" id="form-field-1-1" placeholder="Text Field" name="telefone[]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" />   
</div>

Comment: so how would i go about then to make it an array instad of a string?

Comment: the textarea was my nubie mistake, it supouse to be text

Comment: by the way... $usuario comes from other class

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call `prepare` and `bind_param` in the loop. Prepare the statement once, then call `execute()` in the loop.

Comment: Put the HTML in the question the same way you put the PHP. Paste it in, then use Control-k to mark it as code and it will be displayed properly.

Comment: how do i remove prepare and bind_param if the table´s fields are in it? if i remove it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['telefone']` is an array, so you need to loop over it with calling the setter.

```
foreach ($_POST['telefone'] as $tel) {
    if ($tel) {
        $tlfn->setTelefone(trim($tel));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, my controller is working with your change... however my DAO repets the first element of the loop twise. I have done this change ->    foreach ($tlfn->getTelefone() as $telefone) { /*my code as above*/ }, where am i going wrong? or should i use for(){} instad

Comment: I can't see anything that would cause duplication. What does `var_dump($tlfn)` show in the `telefone` property?

Comment: this is what i get object(Telefone)#3 (1) { ["telefone":"Telefone":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "333555444" [1]=> string(9) "777333999" } } whish is good... two diferent numbers.